# Getting Error in Datatable after hiding a column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

In my form I have a selectbox with 2 choise:
When you select one of them my DataTable gotta change his Column:

```js
//Changing TYpe of Price level will change datatable
$('#price_method').on("change", function(){
  //Declare the variable
  var oTable=$('#item_pricelvl').DataTable();
  oTable.clear();
  //Destroying the table and then rebuilding it again
  oTable.destroy();
  //If Selected Price Override   
  if ($(this).val()=="PO"){
    //I gotta hide a column
    $('#item_pricelvl').DataTable({
      "columnDefs":[
        {
          "class":"details-control",    
        },
        {    
          "targets":['_all'],
          "orderable":false
        },
        //I'm hiding the 4th column 
        { "visible": false, "targets": 4 },
        "Column"
      ],
    })
  }else{ //Else I can show all columns
    $('#item_pricelvl').DataTable({
      "columnDefs":[
        {
          "class":"details-control",    
        },
        {    
          "targets":['_all'],
          "orderable":false
        },     
        "Column"
      ],
    }) 
  }  
});

//INSERT NEW PRICE LEVEL INTO THE ITEM PRICE TABLE
$('#insertplvl').click(function(){
  //Checking what method is selected
  if ($('#price_method').val()=="CM"){
    //starting to add the new row into the DataTable, and No columns hiding
    it_det.row.add([   
    "D",
    "COST MARKUP",
    "1",
    "999999999",
    "0.00",
    "0.00",
    "<input type='checkbox' name='chkdet' class='chk_plvl' id='"+ct_row+"'/>"
    ]).draw(false);
  }else{
    //starting to add the new row into the DataTable, and adding just 6 values because of the hide column 
    it_det.row.add([   
    "D",
    "PRICE OVERRIDE",
    "1",
    "999999999",   
    "0.00",
    "<input type='checkbox' name='chkdet' class='chk_plvl' id='"+ct_row+"'/>"
    ]).draw(false);
  }
  //Increasing the counter
  ct_row++;
})
```

```html
<table id="item_pricelvl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>            
      <th>Price Level</th>
      <th>Pricing Method</th>         
      <th>From Quantity</th>
      <th>To Quantity</th>         
      <th>Markup Amount</th>         
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" /></th>            
    </tr>
  </thead>                 
</table>
```

When I try to insert selecting the "POP, I get this Error:

> DataTables warning: table id=item_pricelvl - Requested unknown parameter '6' for row 0, column 6. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Below I'm pasting a screen of this page
[image]
So if it working with all column why I get error when I put a column invisible?

Comment: First of all, this framework is quite sensitive with errors at source table. My suggestion: Create a "valid" table first with plain html and then add your javascript.

Comment: Honestly I'm not understanding what it means??? valid table??

Comment: To your question: You declared in the head of table seven columns (index 6). The head row is used as base for calcutions by this framework. In the else branch you only declared six columns (index 5), but it wants to have seven columns.

Comment: Maybe you should hide the last column and not remove it.

Comment: Ok that's true and what is the better solution to change dinamically column because I need to find the solution how can I show in the pic.

Comment: I'm hiding the 4th column... I'm not removing it

Comment: According your posted source code - at the end- you create a tablebody with one column few.

Comment: you can see my table in the pic above the comments. Last column is the  checkbox

Comment: And the number of all columns are six. And at the previous picture, the number of columns are seven. And I think, the framework takes the real html element as base for calculations.

Comment: yes you right, so how can I change the datatable structure whit the Jquery? I tried with $('#item_pricelvl').html but doesn't working.

Comment: Two ideas: Either you create a second table and switch between both tables, or you use `display:none`instead of `visible:hidden` for the forth column.

Comment: display:none mmmm in the datatable??? I'm not sure is going to work like this

Comment: I solved it !!!!

Comment: Glad to read it. You can post an answer for your own question, so your share your knowlege for other users.

Comment: It was very easy, I wrote a function on change event, inside this I destroying the actual table and I'm going to create a new one with $("table").html("HTML Code") . After that I gotta reinitialize my dataTable $("table").DataTable({ ... code ... })